# Media Queries or JavaScript to hide an element on certain screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

We have a section on the page that needs to be hidden on small phone screens, and appear on larger screens.

The easiest way to do it would be to use CSS media queries.

```css
.section {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .section {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

However, this would keep the section in the DOM, thus potentially making it less efficient.

Alternatively, we could toggle the existence of the section using a state in our JavaScript framework (React in our case, but not important for the question).

My Question is: When is it better to use one, and when is it fine to use the other?

Comment: Note: I've looked at similar questions, but I can't find one that one perfect answer, especially since they seem to be from before Angular, React, or Vue gained traction.

Comment: Efficiency really depends on details, and not always predictable without multiple tests. If it's a large portion of the page, you may want to AJAX-fetch the section depending on the media type, but if it's just one section it's probably better to just leave it there hidden by CSS.